# Entity framework - left join or something similar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I currently have the following tables:

```
AspNetUsers(Id, PasswordHash,....)  //standard ASP Identity 2.0 table
Category(Id, Name)
CategoryUser(CategoryId, UserId)    // link table to turn many-to-many into a one-to-many
```

My classes match these Entities:

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public Int32? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public Int32? Category_ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent_Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserCategory> Parent_UserCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public Int16 CategoryOrder { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

}


[Table("UserCategory")]
public class UserCategory
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category UsersCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser UserCategoryUser { get; set; }

    public bool CanEditCategory { get; set; }

    public bool CanDeleteCategory { get; set; }

    public bool CanViewCategory { get; set; }

    public bool CanChangePermissions { get; set; }

}
```

This query returns the model that is sent to the view:

```
        //Retrive the category-if the user has access
        Password selectedCategory = DatabaseContext.Category.Include("Parent_UserCategories").Where(pass => !pass.Deleted 
                                            && (
                                                (DatabaseContext.UserCategories.Any(up => up.CategoryId == pass.CategoryId && up.UserId == UserId)) 
                                             || (userIsAdmin && ApplicationSettings.Default.AdminsHaveAccessToAllPasswords) 
                                             ||  pass.Creator_Id == UserId)
                                                ).SingleOrDefault(p => p.CategoryId == 1);
```

What I want to do is have a view which will display all of the users and the access they have. I already have the view setup with the post back... but it only displays the permission records that already exist in the database. What I need to list all of the users (regardless if they have a CategoryUser record), and the corresponding CategoryUser record - if they have one.

I have a number of ideas to make this work, but ideally, I would like the most efficient and cleanest solution possible - I'm also trying to avoid LINQ 2 SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a sample to write left outer join in Linq. I leave you with the burden of the adaptation to your problem:

```
var joint = from user in context.Users
            from perm in context.UserPermissions.Where(p=>p.UserId == user.UserId)
            select new {User=user,Permissions=perm}
```

If Users and Permissions share a one-to-many relationship.

and

```
var joint = from user in context.Users
            from perm in context.UserPermissions.SingleOrDefault(p=>p.UserId == user.UserId)
            select new {User=user,Permission=perm}
```

If Users and Permissions share a one-to-one relationship with cardinality 1..0 on both sides: